# In Chinese Language : Special Characters are displaying in middle of sentence

Tags: css

In Multilingual webapplication, Special characters in chinese is displaying in middle of sentence.

Please refer the screenshot [image: click here]

But I need to be like image [image: click here]

I am using font-family as GothamBook.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us some code. Also, I assume you mean that the trailing comma is too high in the first case, you'd like it to be positioned like the second (but using the font of the first)?

Comment: Kindly my code : <h1>祝你今天愉快，<h1> Language is Chinese traditional

Comment: Can you share your CSS, too?